# Shell script rclone push to object storage works when run manually but not programmatically

Tags: bash, docker, nginx, rclone, nginx-rtmp

##### Background

- I have a docker container that runs nginx-rtmp module
- On this container I receive an rtmp stream, that is recorded, transformed to hls and displayed on an html page
- the streaming and displaying via hls works fine

##### Goal

My goal is to record for about an hour (or certain file size), then save the recording, convert to mp4, push to an object storage bucket and then delete the old files. (then record the next hour and so on)

##### Current Implementation

I achieved this by writing a shell script that is executed via the exec_record_done function of nginx-rtmp module

my nginx.conf:

```
...

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server {
        ...
        application live {
                live on;
                recorder all {
                    record all;
                    record_path /var/www/html/stream/mp4;
                    record_max_size 100000K;
                    record_unique on;
                    record_suffix _%d%m%Y_%H%M.flv;
                    exec_record_done /bin/bash /scripts/cleaner.sh $path $dirname $basename;

                }

                ...
        }
    }
}

http {
    ...
}
```

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$1
dirname=$2
basename=$3
newfile="${dirname}/${basename}.mp4"
ffmpeg -y -i $path -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 $newfile &&
rm $path
TIME=$(/bin/date +%Y/%m/%d)&&
rclone sync -P $newfile objstor:bucket/$TIME/ &&
rm $newfile
```

##### Issue

When I run the script manually the whole thing works as intended.
But when run via exec_record_done the script generates mp4 file when the filesize of recording is reached (as intended), deletes flv (as intended) but then will not push to object storage.

I am stumped as to why it works when I run the script manually, but does not when run via exec_record_done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add logging to the script to find the problem. For instance one of your arguments could be empty or something else is going wrong with your `ffmpeg`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

## log errors to /tmp/script_errors file 
exec 2>> /tmp/script_errors

path="${1}"
dirname="${2}"
basename="${3}"
newfile="${dirname}/${basename}.mp4"

ffmpeg -y -i "${path}" -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 "${newfile}"
rm -f "${path}"
TIME="$(date +%Y/%m/%d)"
rclone sync -P "${newfile}" objstor:bucket/$TIME/
rm -f "${newfile}"
```

Comment: That helped; I got 

2023/03/21 07:35:14 ERROR : Couldn't find home directory or read HOME or XDG_CONFIG_HOME environment variables.
2023/03/21 07:35:14 ERROR : Defaulting to storing config in current directory.
2023/03/21 07:35:14 ERROR : Use --config flag to workaround.
2023/03/21 07:35:14 ERROR : Error was: exec: "getent": executable file not found in $PATH
2023/03/21 07:35:14 NOTICE: Config file "/.rclone.conf" not found - using defaults

I will try setting HOME to root , since I store my rclone.conf in /root/.conf/rclone.conf, or set rclone.conf path directly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Answer from Yaser Kalali, I found out rclone couldn't find the rclone.conf. Using --config= option, I told it where to find the conf file.
Now everything works !